# is fine to open a new fragment in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, design-patterns

I want to separate logic fragment from activity but the problem is I make api call and save data in fragment. And when user click a item in fragment. I need to send parcelable data to other fragment to show detail info about item.

Is launching fragment in fragment anti pattern for android ?

I would like to hear some opinion about this matter.

Comment: Dunno why it'd be an anti pattern if there is documentation on it...  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: I think it's an anti-pattern. Fragments are meant to be isolated logic and should not know about each other's existence (and to go even more, they shouldn't know about their owning activity either). You probably want to launch an intent to show the detail info or alternatively, pass that data to the activity (via an interface) and have the activity's implementation communicate that update to the other fragment.

Comment: @cricket_007 If you read that documentation, the communication happens via an activity and by using interfaces. Having fragments directly talk to each other (instance to instance) breaks the principle of fragments being independent pieces of logic/view pairs in my opinion.

Comment: So I need to manage grid adapter in main activity right and setup onItemSelect listener in activity ?  But my question is how to separate logic then ?

Comment: You can do many things. Keep the grid adapter (and the grid itself) in the fragment. when the item is clicked, have your fragment capture the click and pass that into the activity (via an interface that the activity implements). Then the activity will receive this "event" and can do whatever it wants with it, be it communicating with a different fragment on the activity itself (your detail fragment) OR launching another activity on top of the activity stack (a detail activity of sorts).

Comment: I guess according to document. Fragments directly communicate each other with interface but it doenst launch new fragment in fragment.

Comment: No, according to the documentation, fragments DO NOT directly communicate with each other. The communication is channeled via the activity. Try to read the article and see how the flow is managed.

Comment: @kha Thanks. I guess I misunderstood doc

Answer (score 2):

Yes, is totally an anti-pattern, remember that you need to see the Activity as a container and fragments as independent sub-screens, so is the Activity responsibility to manage the fragments. I.e.: If you have a Post activity you can have a PostText fragment, a PostImage fragment and all of that is manage by the activity, every fragment is attached to an Activity.

Comment: But if you use a Master Detail view on a small screen device, Fragments have a callback to the Activity to be replaced by another Fragment. That is a very common pattern.

Comment: Thanks you. So which way is better? I get data from server in activity in onCreate function and pass data to fragment to set grid adapter. Or I get data from server in fragment and setup adapter and pass back to activity ?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes it need to implement dual pane .. too

Comment: In that case is the Activity which changes the fragment regardless of the callback, the question was if its good to change it from inside another fragment.

Comment: Just communicate with your activity and replace the fragment.

Check: https://www.google.com.do/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=communication%20fragmentactivity

Answer (score 0):

It is not a common practice to have a nested fragment inside a fragment even it can be done. However, it would be better to have an activity as the centric container for all your fragments. You can use EventBus (GreenRobot / Otto) to separate the concerns and do all the API calls in another class and send the results by subscribing to this event.

Comment: I am  trying to use rxandroid. Do you have some sample code ? passing data back to activity with rxandroid ?